# FFMPEG - Zoompan image overlay keep ratio

Tags: ffmpeg

With zoompan I can zoom in and out an image overlayed over a video. My problem is that the image ratio is not respected and the image is stretched in something like 16:9

The image in the center is a phone vertical picture, but It result like this: [image: this]

Looks like zoompan is trying to stretch to full width and the height to.. something. How can I keep the ratio while zooming? I tried using `sar` but it doesn't work

Note: I read [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1127759) and I probably should set the size, but how can I set it to keep the original one?

### Edit:

```
-i "vid.mov" -loop 1 -t 1 -i "1.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]format=rgba,scale=1440x2560,setsar=1/1,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':s=720x1280:d=7250:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)',fade=in:st=20:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=77:d=1:alpha=1[im];[0][im]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h - overlay_h)/2:shortest=1" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output_0.mp4
```

With this, in some video format/resolutions it works, in others not

ie: with `.mp4` it works, with `.mov` it doesn't

### Edit2:

here is the log *(names here are not truncated, there is the full path instead of file name)*

> Error: ffmpeg version N-90893-gcae6f806a6 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the
>   FFmpeg developers
>
> Error:   built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
>
> Error:   configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2
>   --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
>
> Error:   libavutil      56. 17.100 / 56. 17.100
>
> Error:   libavcodec     58. 19.100 / 58. 19.100
>
> Error:   libavformat    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
>
> Error:   libavdevice    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
>
> Error:   libavfilter     7. 21.100 /  7. 21.100
>
> Error:   libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
>
> Error:   libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
>
> Error:   libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
>
> Error: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from
>   'C:\AREA\Progetti\VideoEditingDefunti\samples\video\template_religioso_2.mp4':
>
> Error:   Metadata:
>
> Error:     major_brand     : isom
>
> Error:     minor_version   : 512
>
> Error:     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
>
> Error:     encoder         : Lavf58.13.100
>
> Error:   Duration: 00:02:12.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3149 kb/s
>
> Error:     Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661),
>   yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1024x600 [SAR 1:1 DAR 128:75], 3014 kb/s, 24 fps,
>   24 tbr, 19200 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
>
> Error:     Metadata:
>
> Error:       handler_name    : VideoHandler
>
> Error:       timecode        : 00:00:00:00
>
> Error:     Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D),
>   44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
>
> Error:     Metadata:
>
> Error:       handler_name    : SoundHandler
>
> Error:     Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
>
> Error:     Metadata:
>
> Error:       handler_name    : TimeCodeHandler
>
> Error:       timecode        : 00:00:00:00
>
> Error: Input #1, png_pipe, from
>   'C:\AREA\Progetti\VideoEditingDefunti\samples\in\esempio1\1 s.png':
>
> Error:   Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
>
> Error:     Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 720x1280, 25 fps, 25
>   tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
>
> Error: Stream mapping:
>
> Error:   Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main
>
> Error:   Stream #1:0 (png) -> format
>
> Error:   overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
>
> Error:   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
>
> Error: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] using SAR=1/1
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] using cpu capabilities: MMX2
>   SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] profile High, level 3.1
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] 264 - core 155 r2901 7d0ff22 -
>   H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 -
>   http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3
>   deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00
>   mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0
>   deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12
>   lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0
>   bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1
>   b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250
>   keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf
>   mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40
>   aq=1:1.00
>
> Error: Output #0, mp4, to
>   'C:\AREA\Progetti\VideoEditingDefunti\samples\in\esempio1\output_0.mp4':
>
> Error:   Metadata:
>
> Error:     major_brand     : isom
>
> Error:     minor_version   : 512
>
> Error:     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
>
> Error:     encoder         : Lavf58.13.100
>
> Error:     Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661),
>   yuv420p, 1024x600 [SAR 1:1 DAR 128:75], q=-1--1, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24
>   tbc (default)
>
> Error:     Metadata:
>
> Error:       encoder         : Lavc58.19.100 libx264
>
> Error:     Side data:
>
> Error:       cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay:
>   -1
>
> Error:     Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D),
>   44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
>
> Error:     Metadata:
>
> Error:       handler_name    : SoundHandler
>
> Error: [swscaler @ 0000024164404cc0] Warning: data is not aligned!
>   This can lead to a speed loss
>
> Error: frame=   50 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.39
>   bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=4.76x
>
> Error: frame=  107 fps=106 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.76
>   bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=4.72x
>
> Error: frame=  170 fps=113 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:07.38
>   bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=4.89x
>
> Error: frame=  236 fps=117 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:10.14
>   bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=5.05x
>
> Error: frame=  308 fps=123 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:13.14
>   bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=5.23x
>
> Error: frame=  381 fps=126 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:16.18
>   bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=5.37x
>
> Error: frame=  453 fps=129 q=28.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:19.17
>   bitrate= 109.4kbits/s speed=5.45x
>
> Error: frame=  524 fps=130 q=28.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:22.12
>   bitrate=  94.8kbits/s speed= 5.5x
>
> Error: frame=  587 fps=129 q=28.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:24.75
>   bitrate=  84.7kbits/s speed=5.46x
>
> Error: frame=  640 fps=127 q=28.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:26.95
>   bitrate= 155.6kbits/s speed=5.35x
>
> Error: frame=  695 fps=125 q=28.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:29.25
>   bitrate= 215.1kbits/s speed=5.28x
>
> Error: frame=  751 fps=124 q=28.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:31.60
>   bitrate= 265.5kbits/s speed=5.22x
>
> Error: frame=  804 fps=123 q=28.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:33.80
>   bitrate= 310.2kbits/s speed=5.16x
>
> Error: frame=  856 fps=121 q=28.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:35.96
>   bitrate= 349.8kbits/s speed= 5.1x
>
> Error: frame=  906 fps=120 q=28.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:38.05
>   bitrate= 385.7kbits/s speed=5.03x
>
> Error: frame=  954 fps=118 q=28.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:40.05
>   bitrate= 418.9kbits/s speed=4.96x
>
> Error: frame= 1004 fps=117 q=28.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:42.14
>   bitrate= 447.9kbits/s speed=4.91x
>
> Error: frame= 1052 fps=116 q=28.0 size=    2560kB time=00:00:44.14
>   bitrate= 475.1kbits/s speed=4.85x
>
> Error: frame= 1107 fps=115 q=28.0 size=    2816kB time=00:00:46.41
>   bitrate= 497.0kbits/s speed=4.83x
>
> Error: frame= 1161 fps=115 q=28.0 size=    3072kB time=00:00:48.66
>   bitrate= 517.1kbits/s speed=4.81x
>
> Error: frame= 1205 fps=113 q=28.0 size=    3584kB time=00:00:50.50
>   bitrate= 581.4kbits/s speed=4.75x
>
> Error: frame= 1250 fps=112 q=28.0 size=    3840kB time=00:00:52.38
>   bitrate= 600.5kbits/s speed=4.71x
>
> Error: frame= 1294 fps=111 q=28.0 size=    4096kB time=00:00:54.21
>   bitrate= 618.9kbits/s speed=4.66x
>
> Error: frame= 1340 fps=110 q=28.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:56.14
>   bitrate= 672.3kbits/s speed=4.62x
>
> Error: frame= 1384 fps=109 q=28.0 size=    4864kB time=00:00:57.98
>   bitrate= 687.2kbits/s speed=4.58x
>
> Error: frame= 1428 fps=108 q=28.0 size=    5120kB time=00:00:59.81
>   bitrate= 701.2kbits/s speed=4.54x
>
> Error: frame= 1461 fps=107 q=28.0 size=    5376kB time=00:01:01.18
>   bitrate= 719.8kbits/s speed=4.47x
>
> Error: frame= 1503 fps=106 q=28.0 size=    5632kB time=00:01:02.92
>   bitrate= 733.2kbits/s speed=4.44x
>
> Error: frame= 1547 fps=105 q=28.0 size=    5888kB time=00:01:04.76
>   bitrate= 744.8kbits/s speed=4.41x
>
> Error: frame= 1598 fps=105 q=28.0 size=    6144kB time=00:01:06.89
>   bitrate= 752.4kbits/s speed= 4.4x
>
> Error: frame= 1633 fps=104 q=28.0 size=    6400kB time=00:01:08.33
>   bitrate= 767.2kbits/s speed=4.35x
>
> Error: frame= 1676 fps=103 q=28.0 size=    6656kB time=00:01:10.14
>   bitrate= 777.3kbits/s speed=4.33x
>
> Error: frame= 1724 fps=103 q=28.0 size=    6656kB time=00:01:12.14
>   bitrate= 755.8kbits/s speed=4.31x
>
> Error: frame= 1760 fps=102 q=28.0 size=    7168kB time=00:01:13.63
>   bitrate= 797.5kbits/s speed=4.28x
>
> Error: frame= 1784 fps=101 q=28.0 size=    7424kB time=00:01:14.62
>   bitrate= 814.9kbits/s speed=4.21x
>
> Error: frame= 1815 fps= 99 q=28.0 size=    7936kB time=00:01:15.92
>   bitrate= 856.2kbits/s speed=4.16x
>
> Error: frame= 1852 fps= 99 q=28.0 size=    8192kB time=00:01:17.46
>   bitrate= 866.4kbits/s speed=4.13x
>
> Error: frame= 1886 fps= 98 q=28.0 size=    8704kB time=00:01:18.87
>   bitrate= 904.0kbits/s speed=4.09x
>
> Error: frame= 1914 fps= 97 q=28.0 size=    8960kB time=00:01:20.06
>   bitrate= 916.8kbits/s speed=4.04x
>
> Error: frame= 1954 fps= 96 q=28.0 size=    9216kB time=00:01:21.71
>   bitrate= 924.0kbits/s speed=4.02x
>
> Error: frame= 1992 fps= 96 q=28.0 size=    9728kB time=00:01:23.31
>   bitrate= 956.5kbits/s speed=   4x
>
> Error: frame= 2030 fps= 95 q=28.0 size=    9984kB time=00:01:24.89
>   bitrate= 963.4kbits/s speed=3.98x
>
> Error: frame= 2073 fps= 95 q=28.0 size=   10752kB time=00:01:26.68
>   bitrate=1016.2kbits/s speed=3.97x
>
> Error: frame= 2113 fps= 94 q=28.0 size=   11008kB time=00:01:28.35
>   bitrate=1020.7kbits/s speed=3.95x
>
> Error: frame= 2141 fps= 94 q=28.0 size=   11264kB time=00:01:29.51
>   bitrate=1030.9kbits/s speed=3.91x
>
> Error: frame= 2168 fps= 93 q=28.0 size=   11520kB time=00:01:30.62
>   bitrate=1041.3kbits/s speed=3.88x
>
> Error: frame= 2205 fps= 92 q=28.0 size=   12032kB time=00:01:32.18
>   bitrate=1069.2kbits/s speed=3.85x
>
> Error: frame= 2244 fps= 92 q=28.0 size=   12288kB time=00:01:33.80
>   bitrate=1073.1kbits/s speed=3.84x
>
> Error: frame= 2294 fps= 92 q=28.0 size=   12544kB time=00:01:35.87
>   bitrate=1071.8kbits/s speed=3.85x
>
> Error: frame= 2339 fps= 92 q=28.0 size=   12800kB time=00:01:37.75
>   bitrate=1072.7kbits/s speed=3.84x
>
> Error: frame= 2389 fps= 92 q=28.0 size=   12800kB time=00:01:39.84
>   bitrate=1050.2kbits/s speed=3.85x
>
> Error: frame= 2436 fps= 92 q=28.0 size=   13056kB time=00:01:41.79
>   bitrate=1050.7kbits/s speed=3.85x
>
> Error: frame= 2481 fps= 92 q=28.0 size=   13312kB time=00:01:43.67
>   bitrate=1051.8kbits/s speed=3.85x
>
> Error: frame= 2533 fps= 92 q=28.0 size=   13568kB time=00:01:45.83
>   bitrate=1050.2kbits/s speed=3.85x
>
> Error: frame= 2564 fps= 92 q=28.0 size=   13824kB time=00:01:47.13
>   bitrate=1057.0kbits/s speed=3.83x
>
> Error: frame= 2615 fps= 92 q=28.0 size=   14080kB time=00:01:49.27
>   bitrate=1055.6kbits/s speed=3.84x
>
> Error: frame= 2662 fps= 92 q=28.0 size=   14336kB time=00:01:51.22
>   bitrate=1055.9kbits/s speed=3.84x
>
> Error: frame= 2701 fps= 92 q=28.0 size=   14592kB time=00:01:52.84
>   bitrate=1059.3kbits/s speed=3.83x
>
> Error: frame= 2746 fps= 92 q=28.0 size=   14592kB time=00:01:54.72
>   bitrate=1041.9kbits/s speed=3.83x
>
> Error: frame= 2790 fps= 91 q=28.0 size=   14848kB time=00:01:56.56
>   bitrate=1043.5kbits/s speed=3.82x
>
> Error: frame= 2834 fps= 91 q=28.0 size=   15360kB time=00:01:58.35
>   bitrate=1063.2kbits/s speed=3.82x
>
> Error: frame= 2877 fps= 91 q=28.0 size=   15616kB time=00:02:00.18
>   bitrate=1064.4kbits/s speed=3.82x
>
> Error: frame= 2921 fps= 91 q=28.0 size=   15616kB time=00:02:02.02
>   bitrate=1048.4kbits/s speed=3.81x
>
> Error: frame= 2962 fps= 91 q=28.0 size=   15872kB time=00:02:03.71
>   bitrate=1051.0kbits/s speed=3.81x
>
> Error: frame= 3013 fps= 91 q=28.0 size=   16128kB time=00:02:05.85
>   bitrate=1049.8kbits/s speed=3.81x
>
> Error: frame= 3080 fps= 92 q=28.0 size=   16128kB time=00:02:08.63
>   bitrate=1027.1kbits/s speed=3.84x
>
> Error: frame= 3147 fps= 93 q=28.0 size=   16128kB time=00:02:11.42
>   bitrate=1005.3kbits/s speed=3.86x
>
> Error: frame= 3180 fps= 93 q=-1.0 Lsize=   16525kB time=00:02:12.49
>   bitrate=1021.7kbits/s speed=3.86x
>
> Error: video:14336kB audio:2088kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB
>   global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.612608%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] frame I:14    Avg QP:16.64  size:
>   42662
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] frame P:1149  Avg QP:20.03  size:
>   10088
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] frame B:2017  Avg QP:21.44  size: 
>   1235
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] consecutive B-frames:  2.6% 37.5% 
>   2.5% 57.4%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] mb I  I16..4: 30.9% 57.6% 11.5%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] mb P  I16..4:  4.3%  5.9%  0.3% 
>   P16..4: 35.2%  9.9%  7.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:36.9%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] mb B  I16..4:  0.3%  0.5%  0.0% 
>   B16..8: 19.3%  0.9%  0.1%  direct: 2.0%  skip:76.9%  L0:39.8% L1:55.2%
>   BI: 5.0%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] 8x8 transform intra:56.7%
>   inter:84.0%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 33.3%
>   65.5% 24.9% inter: 10.4% 17.5% 2.4%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] i16 v,h,dc,p: 59% 17% 11% 12%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 35%
>   15% 33%  2%  3%  3%  3%  3%  2%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 36%
>   18% 13%  4%  6%  7%  6%  6%  4%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] i8c dc,h,v,p: 52% 17% 24%  7%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] Weighted P-Frames: Y:25.6%
>   UV:17.5%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] ref P L0: 65.1% 15.7% 14.4%  4.3% 
>   0.5%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] ref B L0: 89.8%  8.1%  2.1%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] ref B L1: 98.1%  1.9%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002415f7f8280] kb/s:886.33
>
> Error:

Comment: In my answer to your last Q, I added the s parameter to zoompan, did you try with that?

Comment: @Gyan yes, but this was a fixed size one, I found some other workarounds and actually it seems to work, but not always and not for all video formats.. have a look at the edit please (the scale and sizes are programmatically calculated and put into the string, scale is 2x sizes)

Comment: zoompan needs to be given an explicit size. If no size is provided, it will resize to 1280x720.

Comment: @Gyan thanks! but I still don't understand why my command (in edit section) works in a video taken from phone camera, but with a bigger and longer one it doesn't

Comment: @Gyan I tried to convert my .mov video into .mp4, but with no success

Comment: Share full log of your command.

Comment: @Gyan this is the full log, thanks

Comment: Your input is `1024x600`; all your scale and zoompan sizes should be proportional to that..

Comment: @Gyan oh thanks! is there a way to do it automatically? they should be smaller than this, right?

Comment: No automatic way. Check the video resolution manually. But open a feature request if you want at trac.ffmpeg.org

Comment: @Gyan ok thanks, so w of image should be < than w of video and h of image < than h of video?

Comment: For final use, yes.

Comment: @Gyan thanks a lot

Comment: @Gyan one last question: is there a problem if the video and the image have different ratio? for example video 100x200 and img 90:45? because in a similar case, zoompan is not working at all. I added a PAN to the image and it is no more cropped, but it isn't zoomed as well